# XEN vm disk quota / fstab commented out

Tags: debian, xen, quota, fstab

In order to enable user quota on a debian system I must edit the /etc/fstab (http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Quota-3.html).

But in my case the whole /etc/fstab on the vm is commented out:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# 
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
#/dev/sda1       /               ext3    defaults,errors=remount-ro 0       1
#/dev/sda4       none            swap    sw              0
```

How can I define the user quotas for root partition then if the partition is not listed in the fstab?

The mount command output:

```
tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
procbususb on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (rw)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620)
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try remount root partition:

```
mount -o remount,usrquota,grpquota /
```

command can be added in rc.local